# Can I open an HTML5 client-side database via an iPhone App (objective-C)?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, html, uiwebview, client-side

I am using UIWebView in a regular Objective-C iPhone App.  Web pages displayed in the UIWebView are writing to a HTML5 client-side SQL database via javascript.  I would like to open this database for reading and writing from the iPhone App.  Is this possible? and if so, how do I find the database and can I use the SQLite framework to open them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML5 database lives outside your app's sandbox and can't be accessed directly. If you have control of the web pages being displayed in the UIWebView you can build a relatively simple javascript bridge to fetch the contents and insert them into your own SQLite DB.

Comment: Thank you Kirk and Squeegy.  I will certainly use the Javascript bridge and I think I may simplify things by using key-value storage (localStorage object).

Comment: I don't know if this was true at one point, but it's not now. See the answer below with the db name of 0000000000000001.db.  I'm using this technique so that javascript and obj-c can read/write to the same sqlite3 database and it works.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think its exposed in this way.

First, I don't think `UIWebView`s will have a client side database that persists across multiple sessions (although it might, I haven't tested it).  And second, it certainly doesn't give you direct access to the SQLite database file itself.

Your best bet would be call javascript into the webview with

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString:@"mySqlQueryingFunction()"]
```

letting javascript access the database for you.

Comment: As this is most voted answer in this thread, I must inform other users reading this. Both of these assumptions are wrong (Client side localstorage persists and you can access sqlite file). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067249/how-do-i-access-html5-local-storage-created-by-phonegap-on-ios for more information.

Answer (score 2):

The SQLite databases used by the `UIWebView`'s WebKit instance are actually in `<Application_Home>/Library/WebKit/LocalStorage/file__0/`, e.g. `0000000000000001.db`.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I found this while Googling on the subject and thought I'd update it with the solution.

The localstorage databases are sqlite databases and are stored in <Application_Home>/Library/WebKit/LocalStorage and the database for your app will be something like file__0.localstorage

You can get the path to the file with something like this:

NSString* fullPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library/WebKit/LocalStorage/file__0.localstorage"];

Hope this helps anyone else who's looking into this.