# How do I access HTML5 local storage created by PhoneGap on iOS?

Tags: ios, cordova, local-storage

We are transitioning away from PhoneGap to a truly native iPhone app and we need to access user data stored in HTML5 local storage created by PhoneGap. How do we get at that data so that we can create a seamless update process for the user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tried Mattias' way but I just accessed the webkit local storage database directly and then imported the sqlite3 lib included with the iPhone SDK to extract the values I needed. This is how you access localstorage created by PhoneGap:

```
NSString *databaseName = @"file__0.localstorage"; 

//Get Library path 
NSArray *libraryPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, 
                                                            NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *libraryDir = [libraryPaths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *databasePath = [libraryDir 
                             stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"WebKit/LocalStorage/"]; 

NSString *databaseFile = [databasePath 
                             stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName]; 

BOOL webkitDb; 

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 

webkitDb = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databaseFile]; 

if (webkitDb) {
    MMWebKitLocalStorageController* wkc = [[MMWebKitLocalStorageController alloc] init];
    [wkc updateUserFromLocalStorage:databaseFile];
}
```

Comment: Nice. Do you know if this is documented by Apple somewhere?

Comment: Nope. I got the path from opening up my PhoneGap app in iExplorer and finding a sqlite file in myApp/WebKit/LocalStorage/file__0.localstorage I will update my answer to include the filename.

Comment: Just FYI, but with 5.1, the location of localStorage changes to live under Library/Caches.

Comment: I like to think Apple had a really good reason, but I can't come up with one. It really hurts PG apps, since one could previously assume localStorage was persistent: it is no longer that way, since the Caches directory is neither backed up nor permanent.

Comment: @SteveMoser trying to get this code to work.  I'm having trouble figuring out the imports and stuff for ```MMWebKitLocalStorageController```.  Which libraries do I need to add for that?  I don't know objective-c very well and searching "MMWebKitLocalStorageController" on google just brings up this answer.

Comment: @TomKrones `MMWebKitLocalStorageController` is custom class. I believe all it did was use sqlite3 to open and extract info from the database file. Search for info on using sqlite3 with iOS.

Comment: @SteveMoser Oh man, I think I might be over my head then.  You don't have an example of it do you?

Comment: @TomKrones nope. I don't work for that company anymore.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is currently any native API for accessing the local storage but you could try to create a web view with some JavaScript that dumps the local storage to i.e. JSON.

Create a `UIWebView` that has a `UIWebViewDelegate` delegate that implements the `webViewDidFinishLoad:` method and uses the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` method to trigger a dump.

Something like this, first the page to load in the web view:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
  // download and insert JSON-js here
  // https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

  function dumpLocalStorageToJSON() {
    d = {};
    for(i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++)
      d[localStorage.key(i)] = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));
    return JSON.stringify(d);
  }
  </script>
</head>
</html>
```

Then the finish load delegate method:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
  NSString *localStorageAsJSON = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"dumpLocalStorageToJSON();"];
  // parse JSON and do something useful
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just provide some detail FYI,the LocalStorage save in the database whitch path is

1. `Library/WebKit/LocalStorage/`（UIWebview）
2. `Library/Caches/`（UIWebview）
3. `Library/WebKit/WebsiteData/LocalStorage/`（WKWebView）

Then open the database,execute query `SELECT key,value FROM ItemTable` can get `key` and `value`.The key is NSString,value is NSData,encode with `NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding`,convert to NSString with code:

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 12, `Library/WebKit/WebsiteData/LocalStorage/proto_domain_0.localstorage` seems to be the correct path for the iOS webview, where `proto` is something like `http` and `domain` is something like `localhost`. Whether `_1` etc. might exist or whether this changed for iOS 13 and above is unclear.

The resulting data is an SQLite version 3 database with one table that contains the `localStorage` keys. For some reason it doesn't want to display the values beyond the first byte, setting `.mode insert` and then decoding the hex data was the easiest way to read the data (this was for a path traversal found in an iOS app, where this page was one of the most helpful of dozens but nothing straight up describes the anatomy of the path and filename for localstorage cache in an iOS app data directory).