# Access data stored in window.localStorage in cordova/phonegap in my react native version of the app?

Tags: ios, cordova, react-native

I'm updating (completely re-writing) my app that I wrote in cordova/phonegap to react native.  In cordova I used `window.localStorage` to store persistent data but now that I'm switching react native I don't want all my users to loose their data when this version is approved and they update.  Is there any way to get the persistent data from my cordova app and access it in react native version on the app after the user updates?

#### Update:

I wrote a react native module to solve this problem.  Here's a link:

https://github.com/wootwoot1234/react-native-webkit-localstorage-reader

Comment: Is your data backed up on iCloud?

Comment: @amrhady no, the data is persistent but not stored in icloud.  It's stored using localStorage in cordova.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are using React Native and Cordova in the same project? May I ask how you did that?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this question that was answered here [How do I access HTML5 local storage created by PhoneGap on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067249/how-do-i-access-html5-local-storage-created-by-phonegap-on-ios). Make sure you read the comments because it seems as if apple may have moved it in the newer versions.

If that doesn't work another way I can think of doing it is just loading up a webview in your app (assuming it still has all of the same data in there). Then you could access the local storage from that webview in the application.

Once you are able to read the local storage I would recommend moving it to a better storage option. I know that there is an sql lite adapter made for react native so that might work for you. So if you wanted you could create a native binding found here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#content. Then you would be able to feed that local storage back into your application.